# Unable to create JBoss Seam EntityManager

Tags: java, null, seam, entitymanager, out

This is so frustrating, here is the error log for the past 3 days. I'm not really sure what to do. Please help me. The source is included below.

```
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6) org.jboss.seam.RequiredException: @Out attribute requires non-null value: caseDatabaseSwitcher.currentEntityManager
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.Component.outjectAttribute(Component.java:1764)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.Component.outjectAttributes(Component.java:1755)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.Component.outject(Component.java:1608)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:86)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.icomteq.edd.cases.util.CaseDatbaseSwitcher_$$_javassist_seam_55.switchDB(CaseDatbaseSwitcher_$$_javassist_seam_55.java)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.icomteq.edd.master.bean.DBSwitcherBean.setCaseId(DBSwitcherBean.java:43)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,197 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.icomteq.edd.master.bean.DBSwitcherBean_$$_javassist_seam_54.setCaseId(DBSwitcherBean_$$_javassist_seam_54.java)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.icomteq.edd.master.bean.QuickLinksBean.setCaseId(QuickLinksBean.java:1408)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,207 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,217 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,227 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,227 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,227 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,227 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,227 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.icomteq.edd.master.bean.QuickLinksBean_$$_javassist_seam_19.setCaseId(QuickLinksBean_$$_javassist_seam_19.java)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.setValue(BeanELResolver.java:108)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.setValue(CompositeELResolver.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.setValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:100)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.setValue(AstPropertySuffix.java:73)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:84)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:249)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:93)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:771)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:703)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$2.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:424)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,237 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.component.ContextCallbackWrapper.invokeContextCallback(ContextCallbackWrapper.java:44)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:711)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,257 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,267 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:720)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:675)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:244)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processUpdates(AjaxViewRoot.java:440)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,277 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,287 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,307 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,317 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-05-20 10:52:44,317 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6) Calling quickSearchCleanUp()...
2013-05-20 10:52:44,317 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6) quicklinks bean caseID: 318
2013-05-20 10:52:44,317 INFO  [com.icomteq.edd.master.bean.QuickLinksBean] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6)  ----------------------   :::::::::::::::::::::  ----------------- 1
```

Here is the Java class that produces the error:

```
package com.icomteq.edd.cases.util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.jboss.seam.Component;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.AutoCreate;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Logger;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Out;
import org.jboss.seam.log.Log;

import com.icomteq.edd.master.wrappers.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper;
import com.icomteq.edd.master.wrappers.EntityManagerWrapper;

@Name("caseDatabaseSwitcher")
@AutoCreate
public class CaseDatbaseSwitcher {

    @Logger
    private Log log;
    public static String persistenceUnitName = "edd_case";
    public static String entityManagerPrefix = "java:EntityManagerFactories:";

    public static final String EDD_CASE_ENTITY_MANAGER = "currentEntityManager";
//
    @Out(scope = ScopeType.SESSION)    
    EntityManager currentEntityManager;


    /*
     * Creates a session based EntityManager for the caseID on the users
     * Session.
     * 
     * last updated by: GerryjunA Sept 14, 2011
     * 
     * @param CaseId
     * 
     * @return EntiyManager
     */
    public EntityManager switchDB(Integer caseId) {
    EddCaseDBFactory eddCaseDBFactory = (EddCaseDBFactory) Component.getInstance("eddCaseDBFactory", ScopeType.APPLICATION);
    EntityManagerFactory emf = eddCaseDBFactory.getEddCaseEntityManager(caseId);
    EntityManager cem = null;
    if (emf != null && emf.isOpen()) {
        cem = emf.createEntityManager();
        currentEntityManager = (EntityManagerWrapper) Component.getInstance(EDD_CASE_ENTITY_MANAGER, true);
        if (currentEntityManager != null && currentEntityManager.isOpen()) {
        if (((EntityManagerWrapper)currentEntityManager).getCaseId().equals(caseId)) {
                //  switchDB will reuse currentEntity
            log.info("switchDB will reuse currentEntity : " + caseId);
        } else {
            currentEntityManager.close();
            currentEntityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        }
        } else {
            currentEntityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        }
    } else {
        currentEntityManager = null;
    }
    return cem;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what files I need to show here to help solve this problem, please help :(

The `currentEntityManager` is null.

This is the part of the code that shows the error logs:

```
@Out(scope = ScopeType.SESSION)    
    EntityManager currentEntityManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear, Seam is trying to outject the `currentEntityManager` value but is unable to do so because the variable is `null`. Thus, you need to see why it is `null` (I presume it is because `emf` is `null` or not opened).

You can instruct Seam to not complain when `currentEntityManager` is `null` (using the `required` option of the annotation). However, if you do not expect it to be null, then you need to check the reason.

```
@In(required=false)
@Out(scope=ScopeType.SESSION, required=false)
EntityManager currentEntityManager;
```

Also, it is not clear why you're returning `cem` in that function, and why you're not setting the `currentEntityManager` with the value of `cem`.

Comment: That is the problem to answer a user with '1' reputation. Don't that?